# Best practice: Like button for the website or for the facebook page of the website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am wondering whether it is better to add a like button for my website or a like button for the facebook page of my website.

SEO is important for me, however what is most important is the ability to inform users about updates (ex. new features, new posts etc) aiming to increase their engagement with the website. From that point of view, the facebook page 'like' button seems a better option since users will subscribe to it and receive new posts immediately on their news feed.

On the other hand, friends of existing users that see the 'like' of the facebook page instead of the direct website, may not immediately get what is the facebook page about and leave immediately without exploring the site.

I was wondering if there is something like a best practice for this kind of dilemma. What do you recommend? Is there a way to combine the two together?

Many thanks for your time and thoughts.

Kind Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

That is a big dilemma. You, the website owner, can combine them together by having a page tab app on your facebook page that points to an iframed version of your website.  Most big companies are maintaining both a facebook page as well as a real website.  Check out companies like coca-cola, etc.  But what it really comes down to is money.  How much more money can your company make if you maintain both?  Give it a test and see if by having a facebook page presence really drives revenue to your business. Be sure to monitor it in a way so you can be sure your advertising dollars, by investing in a facebook page, are spent wisely. Bob Parson says it best in rules #9 & 10 of his 16 rules (http://www.bobparsons.me/bp_16_rules.php?ci=21428).